# Why isn't weights normalization required in SVM?

Tags: optimization, svm, hinge-loss

As I understand :

Distance from $x_0$ to the hyperplane $a$: $ \rho(x_0, a) = \frac{|<w, x_0> + b|}{||w||}$

We require $ min\  |<w, x_0> + b| = 1$, so $min \frac{|<w, x_0> + b|}{||w||}$ will be $\frac{1}{||w||}$

So in order to maximise distance to the closes instance we minimise $||w||$

Then we weaken and unite some restrictions to get to the hinge loss : $L(y, z) = ||w||^2 + C \sum max(0,\ 1 - y_i z)$

I implemented Linear SVM, and it works without weights normalization.

**Why can we still use same formula for loss and gradient, even if we can't say that $min\  \rho = \frac{1}{||w||}$ ?**

my implementation in python:

```
class SVM:
def __init__(self, max_iter):
    self.w = None
    self.bias_w = None
    self.max_iter = max_iter

def fit(self, X, y):
    y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    bias = np.ones(X.shape[0])
    self.w = np.random.rand(X.shape[1], 1)
    self.bias_w = np.random.rand(1, 1)
    
    for i in range(self.max_iter):
        for j, xi in enumerate(X):
            #self.w /= np.min(X @ self.w + np.tile(self.bias_w, (X.shape[0],1)))
            #self.bias_w /= np.min(X @ self.w + np.tile(self.bias_w, (X.shape[0],1)))
            self.w -= 1e-4 * self._calc_grad(xi, y[j], self.w, 1e-3).reshape(-1, 1)
            self.bias_w -= 1e-4 * self._calc_grad_bias(xi, y[j], self.w, 1e-3) 
            

def predict(self, X):
    bias_w_tiles = np.tile(self.bias_w, (X.shape[0],1))
    return ((X @ self.w + bias_w_tiles ) > 0 ).astype(float)

def _calc_grad(self, X, y, w, C):
    grad = 0
    distance = np.max([0, 1 - y * (X @ w + self.bias_w)])
    return w if distance == 0 else w - C * y * X.reshape(-1 , 1)
                   
def _calc_grad_bias(self, X, y, w, C):
    grad = 0
    distance = np.max([0, 1 - y * (X @ w + self.bias_w)])
    return 0 if distance == 0 else self.bias_w - C * y
```